Confirming LinkedIn Developer Apps to use for LinkedIn Share Button functionality
I am reaching out on behalf of one of my customers (Jacobs). They recently moved to a new ATS (Avature) and the LinkedIn "share" functionality for jobs on their careers site is no longer working. I am trying to help them confirm the app they need to use so that the "share" functionality works.
From the screenshots below, can you please tell me if the customer needs to delete these two apps and create a new one, or do they need to add one of the apps that is already created? Thank you!
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am trying to confirm a question on behalf of my customer. They simply need to know which app from the LinkedIn Developer site they need to add for the "share" to LinkedIn functionality to work in their careers site.
